# Term for space in a bank where tellers work

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there a term for the work area inside a bank branch, the "behind the counter" area where tellers work and cash, checks, deposit slips, etc. are kept?

Comment: Do you have a general context for this? Are you trying to translate from another language or are you trying to find a word you know of but just can't remember?

Comment: Is there a reason *behind the counter* is not sufficient?

Comment: Just curious if there was a more succinct term... Thanks for all the help!

Comment: The people who work there might call it the *front office*. As opposed to the *back office*, which in other businesses is where all the real work gets done. I've never been in the back office of a bank, but I imagine it's where they jump up and laughing and throwing banknotes into the air, like bank-robbers after a successful heist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an authoritative citation, but my understanding is that within the banking industry, this area is called the *teller line*.

Comment: ...and Googling supports this notion. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Since there isn't a single word for specifically a bank teller's work area, the next goal would be to find the most concise description, which may vary by context.  *Behind the counter at the bank* or *bank tellers' work area* are probably the best context-independent phrases, though when context is present, it may allow shaving those phrases down to *work area* and *behind the counter*.

Answer (score 1):

In banks where the teller is in an enclosed area with but a small opening through which to transact business, that area is called a ***cage***. It's conceivable that the term's been pressed into service to describe by analogy any space a bank teller works in — but I am unfamiliar with, and (after a cursory glance at a few of the results of searching Google Books for `teller cage`) see no evidence of, such use. The first 100 search results at Google Books for `"a|the teller|tellers in the" -"teller|tellers in the bank"` yield no other possible word for what you seek. So, as [Daniel δ has suggested](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50998), use a phrase, like ***behind the counter at the bank***.